# Stop autosaving after the closing the UIDocument

Tags: iphone, ios

Created a subclass of`UIDocument(XDocument)`, that takes some to save to save document due to large amount of data.

So when I am closing the `XDocument` instance with closewithcompletionhandler and it is closed successfully and returned to success block but after some time it is observed the `autosavewithcompletionHandler` is called after the document is closed successfully. 
Am I missing any parameter to before closing the document?
What are precautions to be taken before closing the `UIDocument` subclass?

Thanks for any help and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best answer, but what I ended up doing was closing the document and then deleting it in the completion handler.  Something like:

```
NSURL *url = _document.fileURL;
[_document closeWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSFileCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
            [coordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL:url options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForDeleting error:NULL byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) {
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:newURL error:NULL];
            }];
        });
    }
}];
```